# Activity not declared in AndroidManifest.xml even if it is

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

Suddenly I get the following error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class.

Although I have declared in the file `AndroidManifest.xml` all the activities of my application.
Does anyone know how to fix this error?
Thank you all

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.uniparthenope.jacoe.homework_tmm">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is my `MainActivity.java`, in which I call the activity `SignUpActivity.java` through an Intent.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

ChatFragment chatFragment;
CallsFragment callsFragment;
StatusFragment statusFragment;
PhotoFragment  photoFragment;

String[] tabTitle = {"FOTO", "CHIAMATE", "CHAT", "STATO"};
int[] unreadCount = {0, 0, 5, 0};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    Toolbar toolbarapp = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Whatsapp_tmm_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarapp);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_button, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.login:
             Intent login = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
             startActivity(login);
             finish();
             return true;
```

Comment: For which activity are you getting this error? How are you starting the activity?

Comment: have you subpackages in your projects ?

Comment: @Sagar I'am getting this error in the MainActivity, precisely when I call the SignUpActivity. I'am starting SignUpActivity using an intent.

Comment: @Derlin No only one packages

Comment: can you update your question with the code with which you are starting the MainActivity?

Comment: @Sagar Done ;).

Comment: Everything looks Ok. Can you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Sorry, but how can i do it?

Comment: Just go to `Build -> Clean Project` then `Build -> Rebuild Project` from your android studio

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling the application, I fix it, thanks to everyone ;)

Answer (score 12):

try to sync with  " sync Project with Gradle files"  inside Android Studio->Files->Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Sometime we miss to do this after having changes to Manifest.

Comment: Thank you so much This is Actually Work For Me :)

Comment: Sync is inefficient sometimes. Restart of Android Studio fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Android Studio 4.0.1, android gradle 4.0.1 build gradle 6.1.1 and could not resolve it with the answers here.

What eventually fixed it for me was going to my app folder and deleting the entire .gradle folder, then invalidating cache and restarting. Normal cache invaldiation didn't work. Rebuilding, cleaning, syncing with gradle: None of it worked without me going in and deleting the entire .gradle folder.

Answer (score -1):

Try to give the activity name as the package name and the activity name.
like,

```
<activity name="com.uniparthenope.jacoe.homework_tmm.MainActivity" />
```

this will take the id from the described location.

Comment: Giving [dot] before activity name expands to this. Why explicitly writing complete name?